# Coffee Script TypeError in compiler when running Mocha.js unit tests

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

So I am trying to run unit tests with Mocha and Chai that are written in CoffeeScript.  I know that Mocha has exclude coffeescript since 1.0 so I am passing the compiler flag `mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script`.  What ends up happening is that whenever I try to require a file in the test the compiler complains with this error.  Otherwise it runs fine.

```
/usr/local/lib/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script.js:36
      throw err;
            ^
TypeError: In /Users/chietala/workspaces/twl/test/buttonTest.coffee, Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined
    at indexOf (native)
    at Assign.exports.Assign.Assign.isStatement (/usr/local/lib/coffee-script/lib/nodes.js:1147:72)
    at Block.exports.Block.Block.compileNode (/usr/local/lib/coffee-script/lib/nodes.js:262:27)
    at Block.exports.Block.Block.compileWithDeclarations (/usr/local/lib/coffee-script/lib/nodes.js:308:19)
    at Block.exports.Block.Block.compileRoot (/usr/local/lib/coffee-script/lib/nodes.js:282:19)
    at Block.exports.Block.Block.compile (/usr/local/lib/coffee-script/lib/nodes.js:244:21)
    at exports.compile.compile (/usr/local/lib/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script.js:31:51)
    at Object.require.extensions..coffee (/usr/local/lib/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script.js:13:17)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:300:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:297:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:288:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:487:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

All thats in my test file is the following

```
  ButtonConsumer = require '../button/base/coffee/ButtonConsumer'
```

And ButtonConsumer looks like this.

```
 class ButtonConsumer
  constructor: ->
```

directory structure is

```
/
   test
      buttonTest.coffee
   button
      base
        coffee
           ButtonConsumer.coffee
```

It's pretty bare bones that's why I'm really confused. I'm running Node v0.8.1, Coffeescript v1.2.0, and mocha 1.2.2.

Comment: No the problem is that Mocha doesn't work with Coffeescript 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocha does not work with CoffeeScript 1.2.  Upgraded to 1.3.3 works fine.